# how to hide URL of pages when Redirect from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to hide the URL of page when I redirect from one page to another. How can I do this except by using server.transfer method. I urgently need it. Please give me solution soon.
I am using
Asp.net, C#

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried Server.Transfer for this but when I click on Hyper Link then it show the URL. so I want to use some another method except Server.Transfer.

Comment: Try and use Server.Execute();

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFrame to show the new URL. For example, Create a page a.aspx with an iFrame in it. on the code behind set the source property of the IFrame to the new URL which you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> Server.Transfer

If you have send the request from "form1.aspx" redirect to "form2.aspx". On the browser url will still "form1.aspx"

Comment: But what I should used at the place where I used Hyper link to redirect. For Example Menus.

Comment: The same logic applies here too. Replace your redirects with Server.Transfer containing the destination URL